# Why is there negative sign as well as positive sign with currents flowing into node for KCL

Tags: circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws

I was studying single node-pair analysis and where i encountered this issue. I dont get why in the last line we have written -v1/100 and -v1/25 when current is flowing into the node but at the same time+o.2v1 when it is also entering the node.[image]

Comment: Hint: don't overthink the sign (+/-). A current with a positive (+) value flowing **into** a node is the same as a current with a negative (-) value flowing **out of** the node. The + or - sign are **a choice** and you're **free to choose** them. After you solve the actual values for currents and voltages, getting a negative value simply means that the direction (of current) or polarity (of voltage) is the opposite of what you choose. Which is fine!

Comment: Ignore the i1, i2, i3, i4 labels, write KCL for the right node. A positive v1 will cause current to leave the right node through the resistors.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie the thing is for 2 currents it the sign is taken as negative when current is entering the node but at another it is considered to be positive while entering the node

Comment: @Mattman so it means the current directiins given are wrong??

Comment: The current directions of i1, i2, i3, i4 were defined by the book author, they are not right or wrong. However, they may be negative, meaning that the current is actually flowing opposite the arrow.

Comment: @Mattman944 but why write -v1/100 and -v1/25

Comment: Current flows from positive to negative through a resistor. The right node is defined as positive v1.

Comment: Problems root from your misunderstanding of Ohms law. Otherwise you would have correctly deducted the relationship between v1 and i1 across 25 ohm resistor for example. It is -v1/25 not +v1/25.

Answer (score 3):

Signs of current in a circuit are just conventions chosen at your convenience.

I can say a current of \$1A\$ flows from node A to B. I can also say that current of \$-1A\$ flows from node B to A. **Both assumptions are correct**. Magnitude and sign, both matter.

Consider following circuit-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBF0Se.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In both circuits I assume voltage between A and B, \$ V_{AB}= +V_1\$ which is equal to \$+10V\$

**In the first circuit**, I assumed: The direction of \$i_1\$ is "downwards" ie., from A to B.

Since \$i_1\$ enters node A and leaves node B, by ohm's law, $$i1 = V_{AB}/R_1= +V_1/R_1=+10/2=+5A$$

**In the second circuit**, I assumed: The direction of \$i_1\$ is "upwards" ie., from B to A.

Since \$i_1\$ enters node B and leaves node A, by ohm's law, $$i1 = V_{BA}/R_1= -V_1/R_1=-10/2=-5A$$

So which assumption and calculation was "correct"? Both are correct. Just sign of current changes if you assume its direction to be opposite.

**Apply this concept to your circuit in the question-**.
Author assumed the directions of currents at his convenience in the circuit. Then,

$$i_1=-v_1/25$$
$$i_4=-v_1/100$$
$$i_{10}=-v1/10$$

Author also assumes that all currents entering node B as positive, and all currents leaving node B as negative. Again, this is his choice, not a rule.

With this assumptions, apply KCL at node B-

$$i_2+i_4+-i_{B\to D}=0$$

$$(i_1+i_{10}+i_{C\to A})+i_4+-i_{B\to D}=0$$

$$\implies \frac{-v_1}{25}+\frac{-v_1}{10}+0.2v_1+\frac{-v_1}{100}+-2.5=0$$

Comment: i still dont get how can i1=−v1/25
i4=−v1/100
i10=−v1/10

Comment: Well, I tried my best.